# Do I Need Cursors?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor

Just to say up front, I’m working with an existing schema (that isn’t exactly the best) and I have no control over it.  I must work with it - I can't change it one bit.

There is one company table with a record for each company, then each company gets its own set of tables that represent the business operations.  To begin with, I’m interested in a specific table for each company.  My task is to generate a single recordset output from all the companies’ “MyTables”

Here’s a sample of what I have:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Company](
    [timestamp] [timestamp] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [Short Code] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [Company$0] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED([Name] ASC))
```

If I SELECT all the Names from the Company table, I get (e.g.)
“Company A”, “Company B”, “Company C Inc.”

And then I have one table for each company (all company specific tables have the exact same column definitions) with the following names (in company name: spaces remain, periods changed to underscores):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Company A$MyTable](
    --Various columns
)
```

The “MyTable” name for “Company C Inc.” would be [Company C Inc_$MyTable]

I was thinking of doing the T-SQL in a stored proc and then consuming that from the C# code that will present the data.

With my limited SQL skills, I’m guessing I need to use cursors.  Since I’ve not done much with cursors, I’m hoping someone here could give me a head start with this.

Thanks,
--Ed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a method which does not use a cursor.  It is based on a method which will turn a list of values into a string using "FOR XMLPATH"

```
declare @Table4Company table(CoName varchar(30))
declare @sqlCMD varchar(max)
Insert @Table4Company Select distinct (Name) from Company
Select @sqlCMD =
(SELECT
  STUFF(
    (
    SELECT
      'UNION  Select * from [' + REPLACE(CoName,'.','_') + '$MyTable]'
    FROM @Table4Company
    FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 6, ''
  )
)
--Select @sqlCMD
```

You did not state what version of SQL you are supporting and the code above will not work in every version.  I tested the code above in SQL2K8.

BTW Who creates the new company name table every time a new company is added?

Answer (score 2):

Try this one out, this will work as long as your table structure for all [Company A$MyTable] are all the same

```
DECLARE @TableName as nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @StringSQL as nvarchar(max) = ''
DECLARE MY_CURSOR Cursor 
FOR 
SELECT  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS INNER JOIN
Company ON INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME = Company.Name 

OPEN  MY_CURSOR
FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR
INTO @TableName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        SET @StringSQL = @StringSQL + 'Select ''' + @TableName + ''', * from [' + @TableName + '$MyTable] UNION '
        --PRINT @StringSQL
        FETCH NEXT FROM MY_CURSOR INTO @TableName
    END
CLOSE MY_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE MY_CURSOR
--This removes the last union
SET @StringSQL= LEFT(@StringSQL,LEN(@StringSQL)-6)
EXECUTE  (@StringSQL)
```

Comment: I would **never** use a cursor to just concatenate strings!